# Regarding task creation for Second Working day of every month using Cron

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want a task scheduler to run on every month Second working day in Snowflake using CRON.
Can anyone reply back to my query.

Comment: Hi - what's your definition of a working day?

Comment: Business Day(only from Monday to Friday)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following expression 0 0 2 * 1-5